# Is there a flaw with generating random percentage values and then checking the percentage?

Tags: statistics, random

I am developing a game project, where I have to make a lot of decisions in the form: "Place object X?". I want to say yes in Y% of the events, where I specify Y as a constant. I am using a random generator that guarantees uniform distribution on its output to make the decisions. I generally request a random value between [1,100] to get a human readable "percentage" value. Then, I apply a condition in the form: "if percentage <= limit: yes, else: no" to make the decision about placing the current object. Here "limit" is the constant Y, e.g. "40" for 40%. Note that I don't want a guarantee on the ratio of yes/no decisions for all events, rather I making the decisions for each event independently. Is this approach flawed from a statistical / mathematical point-of-view?

As an alternative, I could imagine asking a [0,1] value (as a representation of no/yes) from the random generator and specifying a non-uniform distribution to the generator [0.6,0.4] following the previous example. However, I don't know if this approach is better / worse / "it depends" compared to my current approach.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Nothing wrong mathematically from your approach to generating uniformly distributed values in $(a,b)$ from a routine that generates such values in $(0,1)$.  From a programming standpoint it makes sense to want to reuse a well-tested random number generator, but describing the possible flaws and tests for such code goes beyond what you ask (and beyond what can be reasonably covered in one Answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using a Bernoulli-distribution Ber$(p)$ instead. $p\in[0,1]$ is the probability of saying yes (for example). It usually is attributed with flipping a coin. If you want you could also choose $p$ at random, for example using a uniform distribution on [0,1]. Hope I understood you correctly

Comment: Thank you! I think Bernoulli-distribution is exactly what I need to make a yes / no decision based on a p value.